# How to debug nodejs code in render process of electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, render, electron

I'm a newbie of WEB and NODE. I want to make a desktop application with electron.But I found that I can't debug the nodejs code in render prosess with CDT.
It's like that

```js
<script>
    console.log("abc123");
    require('./assets/imports')
    require('./assets/ex-links')
    require('./assets/nav')
    require('./assets/demo-btns')
    require('./assets/code-blocks')
    require('./assets/normalize-shortcuts')
</script>
```

["the javascript code in index.html of electron-api-demo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCDdl.png)

How can I track and breakpoint the code in './assets/import'.

PS:I can see the output of "console.log("abc123");" in CDT.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think that I hava known how to.The reason why I can't track './assets/imports' is that I can't open the file in CDT.

[I can't find any js file below the 'assets' folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul9Am.png)

BUT,finally,[I found I can search any js file I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAAqW.png)

So, I can track it and set a breakpoint in it.

What a nood!!! ^_^